# How to change web folder to public_html

Tags: symfony

I have developed a website using Symfony3 and now want to deploy it using a shared hosting, Hostagator. How do I change the web folder in my Symfony project to public_html?

I know that in order to upload it to my cpanel, I have to copy the contents of my web folder to public html. And all the other files with the exception of the vendor and var/cache do not need to be copied. What modifications do I need to make to my code in order to run it?
I currently get this error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'InvalidArgumentException' with
>   message 'Unable to load class
>   "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Controller\ControllerResolver"' in
>   /home4/igbahigui/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/ClassLoader/ClassCollectionLoader.php:265

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this link](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/configuration/override_dir_structure.html), you should be able to copy all the files from the "/web" folder to "/public_html". You might need to change a config for the var directory though.

The other directories you need to ftp over at one level higher. In particular your controller and twig files: the app and src folders.

Edited my answer below this line:

Your directory structure should be like this:

```
| -- /app
| -- /bin
| -- /src
| -- /var
| -- /vendor
| -- /public_html
```

So your /app and /src folders should be higher up compared to your "public_html" folder. Is it possible to ftp to your hosted server like that. I believe that is the problem.

Comment: Thanks for your response. However, I seem not able to get it to work. In the public_html/app.php, and public_html/app_dev.php I have:
$loader = require __DIR__.'/public_html/app/autoload.php';
include_once __DIR__.'/public_html/var/bootstrap.php.cache';

Comment: Edited my answer - take a look.